# Do external coolers really help with noise?

Tags: ps4, hardware

I saw on the internet some external coolers for PS4 which are prepared to install on the back of console. Does this solution really help with reducing the noise of the working console? During play some games I hear that my PS4 PRO works really loud, but I'm not sure that adding some extra coolers reduces this problem.

If it's going to be an unnecessary gadget that takes up space on the console shelf, I'd rather forgo its purchase. So, has anyone used such a solution and is satisfied with the results?

Comment: I can't speak for the PS4, but I have once bought an external fan for an Xbox 360. All it really did was make my console louder than a vacuum cleaner.

Comment: @Nolonar So this solution did not lower the temperature of the device despite increasing the noise?

Comment: Hard to say. I did not notice an improvement in performance, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this solution, infact i don't even own a PS4 but i am a PC Enthusiast but it should definitely improve noise. Those external cooler solutions are there to improve heat transfer away from the heat producing components, so your microchip (-> Processor) and also have an overall higher thermal capacity through more metal.

Furthermore, a larger fan can be attached to greatly improve the air that passes through the cooler and therefore increase cooling capacity of the device. This could not only lead to lower noise but also potentially higher performance because the chip stays cooler allowing it to draw more power (another whole topic but generally the more cool the more faster). Be aware tho that not every fan is the same so you could get some noisy fan that really sucks if you cheaped out but it will almost certainly be better than the standard cooling solution.

Assuming you dont know much about physically modding a PS4 or building PCs this may be a very risky operation to make and just some simple dusting of your PS4 could do wonders.

Side Note: Good Fans to suggest here would come from companies such as "Noctua" (eventho they have some ugly turd and tan coloured fans they are by far the best performing) or "beQuiet!".

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your very interesting reply. I was just thinking about external cooling systems as I don't want to open and modify the interior of my console. But for now, I just think about leaving my PS4 as it is. I'm pretty sure that an upgrade of the cooling system to make less noise is not that necessary.

Comment: I am not sure on how those external cooling systems would look without opening your PS4 tbh. But hey see the positive things here. You can annoy your neighbours with your homemade jet engine!